# Add an animation to a visual element using triggers on Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, xamarin

I would like to add an animation to `MyFrame` when the user changes the current item of the carousel view. I would like to do it if it is possible using a trigger. This is my XAML:

```
<CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
   <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <StackLayout>
            <Frame x:Name="MyFrame">
               <StackLayout>
                  <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
               </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
         </StackLayout>
      </DataTemplate>
   </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>

   <CarouselView.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger Event="CurrentItemChanged">
            <triggers:ScaleAction/>
        </EventTrigger>
   </CarouselView.Triggers>
</CarouselView>
```

Here is the trigger action:

```
public class ScaleAction : TriggerAction<VisualElement>
{
    protected override void Invoke(VisualElement sender)
    {
        (sender as CarouselView).ScaleTo(0.5);
    }
}
```

So my question is, **how could I send the current frame to the trigger action?**

Answer (score 1):

There is an  event in Frame called Propertychanged,you can set a trigger
on frame like:

```
 <Frame.Triggers>
                            <EventTrigger Event="PropertyChanged">
                                <local:Myaction/>
                            </EventTrigger>
                            
                        </Frame.Triggers>


public class Myaction : TriggerAction<Frame>

    {
        protected override void Invoke(Frame sender)
        {
          
            sender.ScaleTo(0.5, 2000);
        }
    }
```

so it can work like you want.

Comment: But I still have the same issue, how could I get the `MyFrame` from the `sender`?

Comment: I update the answer

Answer (score 0):

You already have your CarouselView in the trigger action as the sender variable. CarouselView has a `CurrentItem` property. You should be able to take that item and cast it to a Frame

Comment: I think the `CurrentItems` comes from the `ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"` so it would be the object time of the `Items`, am I wrong?